# WAI-ARIA: Why does aria-attribute="value" have an "aria-" prefix, and role="xyz" does not?

Tags: wai-aria

While all WAI-ARIA attributes have an `aria-` prefix (like `aria-labelledby` or `aria-required`), the WAI-ARIA attribute `role` doesn't (I guess `aria-role` would be invalid). What's the reason for this?

I've done a search on Google, but while they explain a lot about how to use and implement WAI-ARIA, they don't seem to talk about this specific fact.

http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-primer/
http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/host_languages

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `role` attribute is specified in a separate *W3C Recommendation*: [Role Attribute 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/REC-role-attribute-20130328/).

In the [abstract](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/REC-role-attribute-20130328/#abstract) it says (emphasis mine):

> The role attribute is necessary to support Accessible Rich Internet Applications (WAI-ARIA) to define roles in XML-based languages, when the languages do not define their own role attribute. Although this is the reason the Role Attribute is published by the Protocols and Formats Working Group, **the attribute has more general use cases as well**.

And in the [introduction](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/REC-role-attribute-20130328/#introduction):

> An important (though not exclusive) use case for the Role Attribute is to support [WAI-ARIA].